# C/C++ obfuscator for making .EXEs not flagged as malware

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I've some benign tools that my anti-virus flags as malware.

In particular, I download the prebuild .EXE files, instead of building the C/C++ source code myself (GitHub).

I hope that if I build the obfuscated source code locally, that the programs won't get flagged by anti-virus, since the AV probably relies on signature detection.

What are the best approaches of obfuscating C/C++ code, so that (hopefully) different binaries will be created by the Visual Studio C/C++ compiler?

Comment: Create an exception for your tools in your antivirus settings?

Comment: @hlt - Thanks for your recommendation. However, since I distribute the tools to different machines and use them on a dayli basis, I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: I don't know too much about this kind of thing, but I would assume there is a better (more proper?) way of doing what you program is doing without being flagged as malware.

Comment: obfuscating code will only make it more suspicious...

Comment: @VTT - NOT if detection is performed using signatures...

Comment: @Shuzheng I assume that with "signature" you mean some checksum/hashed value of the byte content of the executable file. If so, an easy way to get a different signature is insert some code and recompile: the byte content will be different, so the signature. be careful the code you are inserting is not discarded by the compiler (e.g code that compiler can detect is not used)